# A spoken English sentence construction

Tags: sentence-construction

Can I speak so?:

> 1. Who sits near you? - Near me sits a boy....
> 2. Near the shed was flying a swallow when I looked into the window

Comment: The natural order in English is SOV (Subject - Verb - Object), and we usually put any adverbial element (such as ***near me***) after the verb it applies to. Your example #1 is thus a stylised "inversion" of the natural sequence ***A boy sits near me***, which would normally only be used in poetic/literary contexts.

Comment: 1) sounds like poetry or literature. Not what people say usually. 2) same thing. Also, we say: Can I speak like this? Not "so", fyi.

Answer (score 2):

> Near me sits a boy...

is grammatical and you might very well find it in a tale, though you're far more likely to hear the following in casual conversation

> A boy sits near me.

The same is true with

> Near the shed was flying a swallow

That phrase could be found in a tale too, and in casual conversation you would be far more likely to hear

> A swallow was flying near the shed.

I suppose the reason such phrases appear in tales is that the tale-teller has a heightened concern for the *flow* of information. Consider the difference here:

> In the back of the house there was an old shed. Near the shed was
>   flying a swallow.
>
> In the back of the house there was an old shed. A swallow was flying
>   near it.

**Near the shed** is a *segue* when the sentence begins with it. The second version without the segue is natural and conversational. The first, with the segue, is more formal in its presentation of detail.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence construction is grammatically correct, though maybe a bit stilted and algorithmic.

> Who sits near you?
>   Near me sits a boy.

Is correct and echoes the structure of the question in reverse, however, better might be

> A boy sits near me.

In your other example

> Near the shed was flying a swallow when I looked into the window

the "***swallow***" is probably of main importance, and so should be moved to the front, and of second importance was what it was doing

> A swallow was flying near the shed, when I looked *out* the window.

Keep in mind, you look "***out***" a window on the wider world, you look "***into***" a window to see a smaller space, eg a room.